# Notify method not wake ups the wait method in loop

Tags: java

I have two classes `Threads` and `ProducerConsumer`. In `Thread` I have two threads running: one to add an element and second one to remove whatever the element added.

The problem is that in `consume()` after removing the first element the notify will not wake up the wait method. In the second iteration it is notifying.

My requirement is I want to notify the producer for every iteration. What do I need to do?

```
public class Threads {
    public static void main(String args[]){ 
        ProducerConsumer pc = new ProducerConsumer(); 
        new Thread(){  
        public void run(){pc.produce();}  
        }.start();

        new Thread(){  
        public void run(){pc.consume();}  
        }.start();  
    }
}
```

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class ProducerConsumer {
        LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
        public synchronized void produce() {
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                list.add(j);
                System.out.println(list+"producer");
                System.out.println("producing and adding values"+j);
                   try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }

        }
        public synchronized void consume() {
                for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                    System.out.println(list+"list"+"consumer");
                    list.removeFirst();
                    System.out.println("consuming values"+j);
                    notify();
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When i run this code, it produces a NoSuchElementException. The problem is that following the notify the consume thread does not release the monitor, and so produce will never resume. A simple fix for your code would be to write your consume in a more gracious way, say like this:

```
public void consume() {
    int remaining = 5;
    while (remaining > 0) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println(list + "list" + "consumer");
                final int value = list.removeFirst();
                System.out.println("consuming value " + value);
                remaining--;
                notify();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note how the synchronization occurs within the loop, which means it is released each iteration. This gives the produce thread a chance to grab it. The reason why the produce thread gives it up - allowing the consume thread to get it and hold on to it even though they both declare method synchronization - is because the wait method releases the monitor lock.